# Android listview with nested CursorAdapters?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to implement a variation on a fairly simple Master-Detail view, but can't seem to find anything out there that relates to my particular issue. It's possible and probably that I just am not searching on the right terms, in which case, I'd appreciate a point in the right direction.

Instead of the standard Master-Detail approach that I was originally planning on, I'd like to display the detail in the master Listview as a TextView with ellipsis, and then just display a popup dialog.

For any record in the master table, there will be 1...n detail records, which I need access to when displaying the master ListView.

I've looked at CursorJoiner, but don't think it fits my needs, as it would require the cursors be sorted on the record ID, but for display I want them ordered alphabetically.

Is it possible and a good idea to nest CursorAdapters? In the master CursorAdapter, I could have a new CursorLoader that would load the details for that item. Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Is there a reason to store the detail list in the cursor of the master? Unless I am missing something, I see another approach. Based on the ID stored in the master listview, you can fire another query to fetch the detail records and display them in popup on click of master list view.

Comment: I think something as simple as that would solve the issue - I knew I was probably over-complicating things. I'll give this a whirl and see if it does the trick. I do need to store the data with the master record I think - I need to display the beginning of the detail record in the master listview, then the full details in the popup, and I'll need record id's to launch another activity if the user wants to edit the detail values, but I should be able to accomplish this all this way.